# Intuition behind the integral of the partial derivatives of a function that is zero everywhere, but locally

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

Let $f\in C^1(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R})$, and let $D\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ open. Assume that $f$ is zero everywhere, except on some small ball, i.e.,
$$f|_{\mathbb{R}^n\setminus B(x_0,\varepsilon_0)}=0,$$
where $B(x_0,\varepsilon_0)\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is the ball centered at $x_0\in\mathbb{R}^n$ with radius $\varepsilon_0>0$. Assume further that $B(x_0,\varepsilon_0)\subset D$. Then
$$\int_{D}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}dvol_n=0.$$
The proof being that
$$\int_{D}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}dvol_n=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}dvol_n\stackrel{Fubini}{=}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n-1}}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}dx_i\right)dvol_{n-1},$$
and $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}dx_i=0$ as a result of the fundamental theorem of calculus.

As much as I understand the proof, I cannot grasp the intuition behind the result, since it seems that the contribution (even though extremely small) of $f$ on $D$ has disappeared when looking at its partial derivative.

One intuition that I have is that in order for $f$ to be $C^1$ and fade to zero, it must first grow and then decay ``gracefully''. As a result, its (partial) derivative must increase first and then descend, so that the two contributions cancel each other when we compute the integral.

Does this make any sense? Can you think of any such example in, e.g., $\mathbb{R}^2$?

P.s. For those interested, I came across the above result in the proof of Gauss' Theorem.

Comment: There is no reason for the ball to be "small"; bounded is  enough (and you can replace this with an integrability condition). Although a little circular given the context, Gauss's theorem can be applied to derive the result. if you write $F(x) = (0,\dots, f(x),\dots, 0)$ to be $f$ at the $i$th place and $0$ elsewhere, then $\int_{\mathbb R^n} \partial_i f = \int_{\operatorname{supp} f} \nabla\cdot F =0$. For an example which is not even compactly supported, you can consider $-2x e^{-x^2 -y^2}$ which indeed has zero integral, since it is $\partial_x  (e^{-x^2 -y^2})$

Comment: Thanks for the answer, what is $\mathrm{supp} f$ standing for? Also, is your integral equal to 0 because of Gauss since you can take a surface where the outer vector $\hat{N}$ has zero i-th component?

Comment: well, it should stand for the closure of the set $\{ x\in\mathbb R^n: f\neq 0\}$ but then your boundary may not be smooth. Better to put this set in a big box/ball and then [Gauss's theorem says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem) that the integral of this divergence is zero, because $f$ is zero there. (Sorry, a little tired!)

Comment: (really sorry for the typos. Again, to emphasize, the integral vanishes because $f$ is zero on the boundary.)

Comment: Oh thank you, now I see what you mean! If I take a ball ``big enough'', then on the boundary of such ball the outer flow of (what you called) $F$ is zero, since $F$ is equal to 0 there (being the ball large enough).

Comment: Yes. Also, For a concrete $C^1(\mathbb R^d)$ function that vanishes outside a ball, you can consider $$f(x) = \begin{cases} (1-|x|^2)^2 & |x|<1 \\ 0 & |x|\ge 1 \end{cases}$$.